# why are react native elements being arranged differently on iPhone plus

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, react-native, jsx

I'm working on a react native app.Here's a view of the component I'm working on right now on **iPhone 6s**:

[image]

Here's the exact same code run on iPhone **7Plus**:

[image]

**Question is, why is the layout different (messed up) on iPhone plus ?**

Here's a gist:
https://gist.github.com/M-Boss/553883714a7cf3e6802865193664771e

Some Nativebase components are used in the JSX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it had something to do with the Nativebase *Card* element.Replacing it with my own component fixed the issue.